# R code to analyze genotyping data.

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have this dataframe (`mydf`). I need to match the letters (DNA letters) in column REF and ALT with the colnames ("A","T","G","C") and get the corresponding numerical values pasted together as "REF,ALT". However, there are some lines where I have "snp:+[0-9]" and "flat$" in TYPE column. Now for "flat$" lines I want to sum the ALT values from as many as "snp:+[0-9]" of the corresponding "start" ids and paste that ALT value again as "REF,ALT" (REF value will be same for both "snp:+[0-9]" and "flat$" with same start ID) and get the output as shown in result. How can I make a function to do this?

```
mydf<-structure(c("chr20:5363934", "chr5:8529759", "chr14:9620689", 
            "chr18:547375", "chr8:5952145", "chr14:8694382", "chr16:2530921", 
            "chr16:2530921", "chr16:2530921", "chr14:4214117", "chr4:7799768", 
            "chr3:9141263", "95", "24", "65", "94", "27", "68", "49", "49", 
            "49", "73", "36", "27", "29", " 1", "49", " 1", "80", "94", "15", 
            "15", "15", "49", "28", "41", "14", "28", "41", "51", "25", "26", 
            "79", "79", "79", "18", " 1", "93", "59", "41", "96", "67", "96", 
            "30", "72", "72", "72", "77", "16", "90", "C", "G", "T", "G", 
            "T", "A", "A", "A", "A", "G", "C", "A", "T", "C", "G", "C", "T", 
            "A", "T", "G", "T", "A", "A", "A", "snp", "snp", "snp", "snp", 
            "snp", "snp", "snp:2530921", "snp:2530921", "snp:flat", "snp", "snp", "snp"), .Dim = c(12L, 
                                                                                   8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("start", "A", "T", "G", "C", "REF", 
                                                                                                                 "ALT", "TYPE")))
```

result

```
    start              A    T    G    C    REF ALT TYPE       AD     
 [1,] "chr20:5363934" "95" "29" "14" "59" "C" "T" "snp"      "59,29"
 [2,] "chr5:8529759"  "24" " 1" "28" "41" "G" "C" "snp"      "28,41"
 [3,] "chr14:9620689" "65" "49" "41" "96" "T" "G" "snp"      "49,41"
 [4,] "chr18:547375"  "94" " 1" "51" "67" "G" "C" "snp"      "51,67"
 [5,] "chr8:5952145"  "27" "80" "25" "96" "T" "T" "snp"      "80,80"
 [6,] "chr14:8694382" "68" "94" "26" "30" "A" "A" "snp"      "68,68"
 [7,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "T" "snp:2530921" "49,15"
 [8,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "G" "snp:2530921" "49,79"
 [9,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "T" "snp:flat" "49,94"
[10,] "chr14:4214117" "73" "49" "18" "77" "G" "A" "snp"      "18,73"
[11,] "chr4:7799768"  "36" "28" " 1" "16" "C" "A" "snp"      "16,36"
[12,] "chr3:9141263"  "27" "41" "93" "90" "A" "A" "snp"      "27,27"
```

Comment: The `sum` of values in `flat` based on `snp[0-9]` is not clear.  Does it have to be adjacent previous values?

Comment: Yes the sum is the sum of the adjacent values for corresponding snp[0-9].i.e. the ones with the same start IDs.

Comment: The ref remains same for all the rows with same start IDs, but the ALT for flat has to be the combination of all the snps with the same start ID(except for the flat itself).

Answer (score 3):

```
indx <- sapply(mydf[,c("REF", "ALT")], function(x) match(x, colnames(mydf)))
flat <- grepl("flat", mydf[,"TYPE"])
x <- `dim<-`(mydf[cbind(rep(1:nrow(mydf), 2), indx)], c(nrow(mydf), 2))
add_ids <- mydf[,"start"][mydf[,"start"] %in% mydf[,"start"][flat] & !flat]
toadd <- x[,2][mydf[,"start"] %in% mydf[,"start"][flat] & !flat]
x[,2][flat] <-tapply(as.numeric(toadd), factor(add_ids, levels=unique(add_ids)), sum)
cbind(mydf, paste(x[,1], x[,2],sep=","))
#       start           A    T    G    C    REF ALT TYPE                 
#  [1,] "chr20:5363934" "95" "29" "14" "59" "C" "T" "snp"         "59,29"
#  [2,] "chr5:8529759"  "24" " 1" "28" "41" "G" "C" "snp"         "28,41"
#  [3,] "chr14:9620689" "65" "49" "41" "96" "T" "G" "snp"         "49,41"
#  [4,] "chr18:547375"  "94" " 1" "51" "67" "G" "C" "snp"         "51,67"
#  [5,] "chr8:5952145"  "27" "80" "25" "96" "T" "T" "snp"         "80,80"
#  [6,] "chr14:8694382" "68" "94" "26" "30" "A" "A" "snp"         "68,68"
#  [7,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "T" "snp:2530921" "49,15"
#  [8,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "G" "snp:2530921" "49,79"
#  [9,] "chr16:2530921" "49" "15" "79" "72" "A" "T" "snp:flat"    "49,94"
# [10,] "chr14:4214117" "73" "49" "18" "77" "G" "A" "snp"         "18,73"
# [11,] "chr4:7799768"  "36" "28" " 1" "16" "C" "A" "snp"         "16,36"
# [12,] "chr3:9141263"  "27" "41" "93" "90" "A" "A" "snp"         "27,27"
```

We first create an index matching REF and ALT to the correct columns. A logical index is created locating columns with 'flat' in them. The number vector with all of the matches is created and given dimensions.

To sum the values of ids with 'flat' as the TYPE, we first identify the rows matching the ids and the values themselves. They are then assigned to proper column slots and everything is bound together.

Comment: Yes, and it needs more work. I have to group the "snp:flat" values better.

Comment: I was thinking about `v1 <-  mydf[cbind(rep(1:nrow(mydf), each=2), match(t(mydf[,c('REF', 'ALT')]), colnames(mydf)))];v2 <- tapply(v1, as.numeric(gl(length(v1), 2, length(v1))), FUN=toString)` and then replace the values for the `flat`

Comment: I like that approach. It still leaves the adding by group. My `toadd` variable has to be done by group or it will fail with other examples.

Comment: @PierreLafortune-Not sure why, but your code generated error:Error: dims [product 12684] do not match the length of object [19026]
In addition: Warning message:
In .Method(..., deparse.level = deparse.level) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Comment: What are the dimensions of your full data set? `dim(mydf)`

Comment: dim of mydf: 6342 / 265

Comment: @user277653 Can you try the code I posted in the comments along with  `indx <- grepl('flat', mydf[,'TYPE']);indx1 <- grepl('snp:\\d+', mydf[,'TYPE']);v3 <- sub(', .*', '', v2[indx1]);v4 <- as.numeric(sub('.*,\\s+', '', v2[indx1]));v2[indx] <- unique(paste(v3, ave(v4, v3, FUN=sum), sep=", "))`

Comment: @akrun:> v4 <- as.numeric(sub('.*,\\s+', '', v2[indx1]))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> v2[indx] <- unique(paste(v3, ave(v4, v3, FUN=sum), sep=", "))
Warning message:
In v2[indx] <- unique(paste(v3, ave(v4, v3, FUN = sum), sep = ", ")) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @user277653 It may be better if you show a small example that reproduce the warning.

Comment: I've updated the answer and have tested it on different combinations. It works with the data you provided and other iterations. If you are still getting errors, you need to post different examples. Because these work.

Comment: @PierreLafortune-Could please explain what this line does:x <- `dim<-`(want.result[cbind(rep(1:nrow(want.result), 2), indx)], c(nrow(want.result), 2))??

Comment: It's a way of combining two steps into one. Instead of the long version, `x <- y; dim(x) <- z` you can do ``x <- `dim<-`(y,z)``